# How to efficiently get the sub matrix indexed by another matrix?

Tags: performance, pandas, numpy, matrix

Now I hava a matrix: test_projs, and a index matrix, GT_index

Each element of each row of GT_index means the index of needed element of this row in test_projs. now I wanna to compute the sum of the each row on the select area.

A simple example:

```
test_projs = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3], 1:[4,5,6], 2:[7,8,9], 3:[1,3,5]}, index=[3,4,5])
GT_index = pd.DataFrame({0:[3,2,1], 1:[2,3,2], 2:[1,1,3]}, index=[3,4,5])
b = np.zeros(3)
i = 0
for (index1, row1),(index2,row2) in zip(test_projs.iterrows(),GT_index.iterrows()) :
    b[i]=row1[row2].values.sum()
    i+=1
b
```

and the result of example above is:

[image]

but it's slow. Do you know how to improve the efficiency of it.

Comment: I'm removing the "matlab" label, since the question is not MATLAB-related.

Comment: Your code doesnt work for me. Can you rather use small DataFrames like `test_projs = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3],
                   1:[4,5,6],
                   2:[7,8,9],
                   3:[1,3,5]}, index=[3,4,5])` and add desired output?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, I will give out the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `NumPy` arrays and [`fancy-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) technique with it -

```
arr1 = test_projs.values
arr2 = GT_index.values
out = arr1[np.arange(arr2.shape[0]),arr2.T].sum(0)
```

Comment: Thank your very much!! Your solution is 10x fasters than mine on my machine!